# Custom styles of product flavors in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, gradle, styles, themes

I have a module with several product flavors ('foo' in this example). The base theme (style) is defined within the module.

Now my idea was to modify this theme in every flavor, by adding a styles.xml in #flavor#/res/values/ folder and extend the style, as I did it before in Eclipse, using library project mechanism. But obviously the complete style is overriden. My intention was, that gradle is merging the files together correctly.

- MyApp

  - app
  - src

    - **main**

      - java
      - res\values

        - **main_styles.xml**
    - **foo**

      - java
      - res\values

        - **foo_styles.xml**

main_styles:

```
<style name="Theme.Main" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:title">A title</item>
    <item name="android:subtitle">A subtitle</item>

</style>
```

foo_styles:

```
<style name="Theme.Main" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/foo</item>
</style>
```

What I expect:

```
<style name="Theme.Main" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:title">A title</item>
    <item name="android:subtitle">A subtitle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/foo</item>
</style>
```

What I get:

```
<style name="Theme.Main" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/foo</item>
</style>
```

Any advice?

Comment: I think this is possible, using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30279350/878126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'll only **merge** if they have the same name. Call them both `styles.xml`.

**EDIT:**  It appears that you can't: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/sQTsk35U7Ic

Comment: same problem if both filenames are equal :-/

Comment: Hmmm... it appears that you can't: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/sQTsk35U7Ic

Answer (score 1):

Merging is not possible but the same effect can by achieved by this way (AndroidManifest refers to foo and foo refers to main and main refers to android:Theme.Light)...

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
<application ... android:theme="@style/MyStyleFoo" ...>
```

```
// src/main/res/values/styles.xml
<resources>
    <style name="MyStyleMain" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:title">A title</item>
        <item name="android:subtitle">A subtitle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
// src/foo/res/values/styles.xml
<resources>
    <style name="MyStyleFoo" parent="MyStyleMain">
        <item name="android:background">@color/foo</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```